# Creating a popup upon form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, wordpress, popup

I have a wordpress site, and I'm trying to get a checkbox with "I agree to terms and services" to come up when a user clicks the submit button. A user MUST check this before submitting, and it needs to be in a popup (as opposed to another form field).

I have tried javascript but I'm not very good with it, and of course I've tried editing the actual PHP but that was just more messy than I figured.

You can see it here: http://www.choosewiselybook.com/tell-us-a-story/submit-your-story/

Thanks so much for the help

Comment: You would probably get some more traction if you showed the efforts you've made so far and where they failed.  We can help you with specific problems you have.

Answer (score 0):

A rather direct (slightly hackish) way: the submit button in the linked page could be edited (if you have access to the code) to ask a confirm question like this:

```
<input type="submit" 
    onclick="return cforms_validate('', true) && confirm('You sure?')" 
    value="Submit" class="sendbutton" id="sendbutton" 
    name="sendbutton" style="cursor: auto;">
```

What was added is the `&& confirm('You sure?')` bit which makes sure (in addition to the validate method preceding it) the user clicks "Yes" in the popup dialog.

Comment: this works, the problem is the PHP loops through all forms, and I have another form on the site that I don't want this happening for...

Comment: Then you'd need to recognize the particular form you want this for. Your best bet is php, but I suppose you could also change my suggestion to something like `&& (this.form.id !== "cformsform" || confirm('Sure?'))` making it only work for the form with a particular ID. Note that this makes the hackish solution an even bigger hack :D

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the terms and conditions form as a div element with the following in its css

```
`display:none;`
```

So it starts off unseen.
And a check box and a new submission or confirm button in the html
Next take whatever JavaScript that "submits" or whatever action your submit button is responsible for  moved to the new submit button and add an if statement that is dependent on the box being checked. 
Then you need to repurpose your old submit button with the following javascript:

```
document.getElementById('confimationButton').style.display = 'block'
```

So it will turn visible and pop up.
I hope this is helpful.